# Android JNI call method GetStringUTFLength getting crash

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jnienv

Code

```
std::string abc(const char* param)
{
    JNIEnv *pJNIEnv = GetJNIEnv();

    //TODO : for testing
    jstring jstr = pJNIEnv->NewStringUTF("Ñandú");  //can pass param also
    std::string result = convertJStringToString(pJNIEnv, jstr);


    return result;
}


std::string convertJStringToString(JNIEnv *env, jstring str) {
    const jsize len = env->GetStringUTFLength(str);
    const char *strChars = env->GetStringUTFChars(str, (jboolean *) 0);
    std::string Result(strChars, len);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str, strChars);
    return Result;
}
```

Getting Crash report on Play Store

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> x.abc.xyz <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000071914  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
  #01  pc 000000000001e058  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+88)
  #02  pc 0000000000456740  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+528)
  #03  pc 0000000000456eb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art7Runtime7AborterEPKc+24)
  #04  pc 000000000054a840  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN7android4base10LogMessageD1Ev+912)
  #05  pc 00000000002e6534  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1732)
  #06  pc 00000000002e683c  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortFEPKcS2_z+204)
  #07  pc 0000000000363b30  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI18GetStringUTFLengthEP7_JNIEnvP8_jstring+816)
  #08  pc 00000000001e205c  /data/app/x.abc.xyz-Sor8tcKXEtf7w-3TH6bZFw==/lib/arm64/libnative-lib.so (_Z22convertJStringToStringP7_JNIEnvP8_jstring+44)
```

Unable to understand why this is crash, Mostly crash on Android 8.0. Please don't say pass jstring value NULL is the reason that's I already checked in my code before passing jstring to this method.

Comment: what does GDB say about it? what about a [mcve] ?

Comment: @Shark create any method in cpp file & call  convertJStringToString(JNIEnv *env, jstring str) method. please check update.

Comment: You're passing what appears to be a standard `char` string literal with some extended characters. Have you verified that they are encoded correctly? Also, does the crash still occur if you change the literal into something like `"test"`?

Comment: @Michael A string literal uses whatever the compiler is told to emit as the "execution charset". (That's assuming that the compiler is told the correct "source charset" that the source file author has used.)

Comment: @TomBlodget My point was that whatever that turns out to be might not necessarily be the same as the modified UTF-8 encoding expected by `NewStringUTF`.

Comment: @Michael That is a very important point. With the sample data in the question, that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem on Xiami phone. It was problem with formatting string, before native stacktrace, I've got following error:

```java
2020-07-28 10:35:51.321 6978-6978/cookbook.chapter2 A/okbook.chapter: art_method.cc:530] Check failed: found_virtual Didn't find oat method index for virtual method: int android.icu.text.DecimalFormat_ICU58_Android.getMinimumIntegerDigits()
```

Problematic code was formatting string(precisely last argument of string formatting):

```cpp
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "native", "UTF-8 string with Chinese characters: %s, string length (number of bytes) %d=%d", newStr, newStrLen, strlen(newStr));
```